# Memory not getting released in C# application

Tags: c#

I have a C# program which converts Ebcdic to Ascii. The input files for the program are around 250MB to 300 MB in size, When I am processing by placing single file,in the share path the file processing is happening without any issues, but when there are more than 1 files in the input file location, when the second file is processed to 50% ,I am getting **System.OutOfMemoryException** , I have pasted sample code where I have used garbage collection (after single files are processed) for freeing up the memory. but its not working as expected, at the same time I also made parser object to null and then tried to garbage collection but still getting the same error.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ebcdic2Ascii
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SampleFiles\input\");
             FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.dat");
             StreamWriter[] writer = new StreamWriter[Files.Count()];
             LineTemplate lineTemplate = new LineTemplate(73, "ReservationsData");
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("RESERVATION-NUMBER", FieldType.String, 0, 11));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("CHECKIN-DATE", FieldType.DateString, 11, 6));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("CALC-NET-AMOUNT", FieldType.BinaryNum, 17, 4, 2));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("CUSTOMER-NAME", FieldType.String, 21, 30));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("RUNDATE", FieldType.DateStringMMDDYY, 51, 6));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("CURRENCY-CONV-RATE", FieldType.Packed, 57, 6, 6));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("US-DOLLAR-AMOUNT-DUE", FieldType.Packed, 63, 6, 2));
             lineTemplate.AddFieldTemplate(new FieldTemplate("DATE-OF-BIRTH", FieldType.PackedDate, 69, 4));
             int i = 0;
             foreach (FileInfo File in Files)
             {
                  EbcdicParser parser = new EbcdicParser(File.FullName, lineTemplate);
                  string Outputpath = "C:\\output\\" + File.Name + ".txt";
                  writer[i] = new StreamWriter(Outputpath);
                  foreach (ParsedLine line in parser.ParsedLines)
                  {
                        writer[i].WriteLine(line["RESERVATION-NUMBER"].ToString() + "\t" + line["CHECKIN-DATE"].ToString() + "\t" + line["CALC-NET-AMOUNT"].ToString() + "\t" + line["CALC-NET-AMOUNT"].ToString() + "\t" + line["CUSTOMER-NAME"].ToString() + "\t" + line["RUNDATE"].ToString() + "\t" + line["CURRENCY-CONV-RATE"].ToString() + "\t" + line["US-DOLLAR-AMOUNT-DUE"].ToString() + "\t" + line["DATE - OF - BIRTH"].ToString());
                  }
                  i = i+1;
        
                 GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                 GC.Collect();
                 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the parser this also has garbage collection method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ebcdic2Ascii
{
    public class EbcdicParser
    {
       public ParsedLine[] Lines { get; private set; }

       public EbcdicParser()
       {
        //Empty constructor
       }

       public EbcdicParser(byte[] allBytes, LineTemplate lineTemplate)
      {
        double expectedRows = (double)allBytes.Length / lineTemplate.LineSize;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Parsing started", DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: Line count est {0:#,###.00}", expectedRows, DateTime.Now);

        this.Lines = this.ParseAllLines(lineTemplate, allBytes);

        //Collect garbage
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0} line(s) have been parsed", this.Lines.Count(), DateTime.Now);
      }

       public EbcdicParser(string sourceFilePath, LineTemplate lineTemplate)
        : this(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath), lineTemplate)
      {
        //Constructor with the file path
      } 
     
      public ParsedLine[] ParseAllLines(LineTemplate lineTemplate, byte[] allBytes)
      {
        bool isSingleLine = false;
        this.ValidateInputParameters(lineTemplate, allBytes, isSingleLine);
        
        List<ParsedLine> parsedLines = new List<ParsedLine>();
        byte[] lineBytes = new byte[lineTemplate.LineSize];
        ParsedLine parsedLine;

        for (int i = 0; i < allBytes.Length; i += lineTemplate.LineSize)
        {
            if (i % 1000 == 0)
            {
                //Print progress
                Console.Write(i + "\r");
            }
            Array.Copy(allBytes, i, lineBytes, 0, lineTemplate.LineSize);
            parsedLine = this.ParseSingleLine(lineTemplate, lineBytes);
            parsedLines.Add(parsedLine);
        }
        return parsedLines.ToArray();
     }
     public ParsedLine[] ParseAllLines(LineTemplate lineTemplate, string sourceFilePath)
     {
        return this.ParseAllLines(lineTemplate, File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath));
     }
     public ParsedLine ParseSingleLine(LineTemplate lineTemplate, byte[] lineBytes)
     {
        bool isSingleLine = true;
        this.ValidateInputParameters(lineTemplate, lineBytes, isSingleLine);
        ParsedLine parsedLine = new ParsedLine(lineTemplate, lineBytes);
        return parsedLine;
     }
     private bool ValidateInputParameters(LineTemplate lineTemplate, byte[] allBytes, bool isSingleLine)
     {
        if (allBytes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Ebcdic data is not provided");
        }
        if (lineTemplate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Line template is not provided");
        }
        if (lineTemplate.FieldsCount == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Line template must contain at least one field");
        }
        if (allBytes.Length < lineTemplate.LineSize)
        {
            throw new Exception("Data length is shorter than the line size");
        }
        if (isSingleLine && allBytes.Length != lineTemplate.LineSize)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bytes count doesn't equal to line size");
        }
        double expectedRows = (double)allBytes.Length / lineTemplate.LineSize;
        if (expectedRows % 1 != 0) //Expected number of rows is not a whole number
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected number of rows is not a whole number. Check line template.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void CreateCsvFile(string outputFilePath, bool includeColumnNames, bool addQuotes)
    {
        if (this.Lines == null || this.Lines.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("No lines have been parsed"); 
        }
        ParserUtilities.ConvertLineArrayToCsv(this.Lines, outputFilePath, includeColumnNames, addQuotes);
    }
  }
   }
```

ParsedLine class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ebcdic2Ascii
{
  public class ParsedLine
  {
    public LineTemplate Line_Template { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ParsedField> FieldDictionary 
      { get; private set; } //= new Dictionary<string, ParsedField>();
    public string this[string fieldName]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FieldDictionary[fieldName].Value.Trim();
        }
    } 

    //Constructor
    public ParsedLine(LineTemplate lineTemplate, byte[] lineBytes)
    {
        this.Line_Template = lineTemplate;
        this.ParseLine(lineBytes, lineTemplate);
    }

    private void ParseLine(byte[] lineBytes, LineTemplate lineTemplate)
    {
        this.ValidateInputParameters(lineBytes, lineTemplate);

        foreach (var fieldTemplate in lineTemplate.FieldTemplateDictionary)
        {
            FieldDictionary.Add(fieldTemplate.Key, 
              new ParsedField(lineBytes, lineTemplate.FieldTemplateDictionary[fieldTemplate.Key]));
        }
    }

    private void ValidateInputParameters(byte[] lineBytes, LineTemplate template)
    {
        if (lineBytes == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Line bytes required");
        }
        if (lineBytes.Length < template.LineSize)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
              "Bytes provided: {0}, line size: {1}", lineBytes.Length, template.LineSize));
        }
        if (template == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("line template is required");
        }
        if (template.FieldsCount == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Field templates have not been defined in the line template");
        }
    }

    public string GetParsedFieldValuesCSV(bool addQuotes)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;

        foreach (ParsedField parsedField in this.FieldDictionary.Values)
        {
            sb.Append(addQuotes ? "\"" : "");
            sb.Append(parsedField.Value);
            sb.Append(addQuotes ? "\"" : "");
            sb.Append(this.FieldDictionary.Count < count ? "," : "");
            count++;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

class ParsedField

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Ebcdic2Ascii
{
public class ParsedField
{
    public FieldTemplate Field_Template { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public byte[] OriginalBytes { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalBytesInHex
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(this.OriginalBytes);  
        }
    }
    public string OriginalBytesInDec
    {
        get
        {
            return ParserUtilities.ConvertBytesToDec(this.OriginalBytes);
        }
    }
    public bool ParsedSuccessfully { get; private set; }

    //Constructor
    public ParsedField(byte[] lineBytes, FieldTemplate fieldTemplate)
    {
        this.ParsedSuccessfully = true;
        this.Field_Template = fieldTemplate;
        this.Value = ParseField(lineBytes, fieldTemplate);
    }

    private string ParseField(byte[] lineBytes, FieldTemplate template)
    {
        if (lineBytes == null || lineBytes.Length == 0)
        {
            ParserUtilities.PrintError("Line bytes is null or empty");
            this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
            return null;
        }
        if (lineBytes.Length < (template.StartPosition + template.FieldSize))
        {
            this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
              "Field \"{0}\" length falls outside the line length", template.FieldName));
        }

        byte[] fieldBytes = new byte[template.FieldSize];
        Array.Copy(lineBytes, template.StartPosition, fieldBytes, 0, template.FieldSize);
        this.OriginalBytes = fieldBytes;

        if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.AlphaNum)
        {
            return this.ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(fieldBytes);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.Numeric)
        {
            return this.ConvertNumericEbcdic(fieldBytes, template.DecimalPlaces);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.Packed)
        {
            return this.Unpack(fieldBytes, template.DecimalPlaces);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.Binary)
        {
            return ConvertBinaryEbcdic(fieldBytes, template.DecimalPlaces);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.Date)
        {
            return ConvertDateStrEbcdic(fieldBytes);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.PackedDate)
        {
            return ConvertPackedDateStrEbcdic(fieldBytes);
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.SourceBytesInHex)
        {
            return this.OriginalBytesInHex;
        }
        else if (this.Field_Template.Type == FieldType.SourceBytesInDec)
        {
            return this.OriginalBytesInDec;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
              "Unable to parse field \"{0}\". Unknown field type: {1}", 
              template.FieldName, template.Type.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private string ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(byte[] ebcdicBytes)
    {
        if (this.ByteArrayIsFullOf_0xFF(ebcdicBytes))
        {
            return "";
        }

        //Encoding asciiEnc = Encoding.ASCII;
        //Encoding ebcdicEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
        //string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Convert(ebcdicEnc, asciiEnc, ebcdicBytes));

        //Thank you sx2008
        Encoding ebcdicEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
        string result = ebcdicEnc.GetString(ebcdicBytes); // convert EBCDIC Bytes -> Unicode string
        return result;
    }

    private string ConvertNumericEbcdic(byte[] ebcdicBytes, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        string tempNumStr = this.ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(ebcdicBytes).Trim();

        if (tempNumStr == null || tempNumStr.Length == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(tempNumStr, @"^\d+$")) //Unsigned integer
        {
            string result = this.AdjustDecimalValues(Int64.Parse(tempNumStr), decimalPlaces);
            return result;
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(tempNumStr, @"^\d+[A-R{}]$")) //Signed integer
        {
            string lastChar = tempNumStr.Substring(tempNumStr.Length - 1);

            switch (lastChar)
            {
                case "{":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("{", "0");
                    break;
                case "A":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("A", "1");
                    break;
                case "B":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("B", "2");
                    break;
                case "C":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("C", "3");
                    break;
                case "D":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("D", "4");
                    break;
                case "E":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("E", "5");
                    break;
                case "F":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("F", "6");
                    break;
                case "G":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("G", "7");
                    break;
                case "H":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("H", "8");
                    break;
                case "I":
                    tempNumStr = tempNumStr.Replace("I", "9");
                    break;
                case "}":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("}", "0");//Fixed
                    break;
                case "J":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("J", "1");
                    break;
                case "K":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("K", "2");
                    break;
                case "L":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("L", "3");
                    break;
                case "M":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("M", "4");
                    break;
                case "N":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("N", "5");
                    break;
                case "O":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("O", "6");
                    break;
                case "P":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("P", "7");
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("Q", "8");
                    break;
                case "R":
                    tempNumStr = "-" + tempNumStr.Replace("R", "9");
                    break;
            }

            string result = this.AdjustDecimalValues(Int64.Parse(tempNumStr), decimalPlaces);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
            return tempNumStr;
        }
    }

    private string ConvertBinaryEbcdic(byte[] ebcdicBytes, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        if (this.ByteArrayIsFullOf_0xFF(ebcdicBytes))
        {
            return "";
        }

        //BitConverter requires low order bytes goes first, followed by the higher order bytes. 
        //Bytes are stored in the file in the opposite order, thus need to reverse bytes
        Array.Reverse(ebcdicBytes);
        long tempNum;

        if (ebcdicBytes.Length == 2)
        {
            //If 2 bytes are provided -- assume it's a short
            tempNum = BitConverter.ToUInt16(ebcdicBytes, 0);
        }
        else if (ebcdicBytes.Length == 4)
        {
            //If 4 bytes are provided -- assume it's an int
            tempNum = BitConverter.ToInt32(ebcdicBytes, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Just in case
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
              "Incorrect number of bytes provided for a binary field: {1}", decimalPlaces));
        }

        string result = this.AdjustDecimalValues(tempNum, decimalPlaces);
        return result;
    }

    private string AdjustDecimalValues(long numericValue, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        if (decimalPlaces == 0)
        {
            return numericValue.ToString();
        }
        double result = numericValue / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
        return result.ToString();
    } 

    private string ConvertDateStrEbcdic(byte[] ebcdicBytes)
    {
        string dateStr = this.ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(ebcdicBytes).Trim();
        string result = this.ConvertDateStr(dateStr);
        return result;
    }

    private string ConvertPackedDateStrEbcdic(byte[] ebcdicBytes)
    {
        string dateStr = this.Unpack(ebcdicBytes, 0);
        string result = this.ConvertDateStr(dateStr);
        return result;
    }

    private string ConvertDateStr(string dateStr)
    {
        dateStr = dateStr.Trim();

        if (dateStr.Trim() == "" || dateStr == "0" || 
              dateStr == "0000000" || dateStr == "9999999")
        {
            return "";
        }
        if (Regex.IsMatch(dateStr, @"^\d{3,5}$"))
        {
            dateStr = dateStr.PadLeft(6, '0');
        }

        Match match = Regex.Match(dateStr, @"^(?<Year>\d{3})(?<Month>\d{2})
        (?<Day>\d{2})$"); //E.g.: 0801232 = 1980-12-31; 1811231 = 2080-12-31

        if (match.Success)
        {
            int year = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["Year"].Value) + 1900; //013 => 1913, 113 => 2013...
            int month = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["Month"].Value);
            int day = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["Day"].Value);

            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                return tempDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
            catch { }
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(dateStr, @"^\d{6}$"))
        {
            DateTime tempDate;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "yyMMdd", 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate))
            {
                return tempDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
        }

        this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
        return dateStr;
    } 

    private string Unpack(byte[] ebcdicBytes, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        if (ByteArrayIsFullOf_0xFF(ebcdicBytes))
        {
            return "";
        }

        long lo = 0;
        long mid = 0;
        long hi = 0;
        bool isNegative;

        // this nybble stores only the sign, not a digit.  
        // "C" hex is positive, "D" hex is negative, and "F" hex is unsigned. 
        switch (Nibble(ebcdicBytes, 0))
        {
            case 0x0D:
                isNegative = true;
                break;
            case 0x0F:
            case 0x0C:
                isNegative = false;
                break;
            default:
                //throw new Exception("Bad sign nibble");
                this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
                return this.ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(ebcdicBytes);
        }
        long intermediate;
        long carry;
        long digit;
        for (int j = ebcdicBytes.Length * 2 - 1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            // multiply by 10
            intermediate = lo * 10;
            lo = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
            carry = intermediate >> 32;
            intermediate = mid * 10 + carry;
            mid = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
            carry = intermediate >> 32;
            intermediate = hi * 10 + carry;
            hi = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
            carry = intermediate >> 32;
            // By limiting input length to 14, we ensure overflow will never occur

            digit = Nibble(ebcdicBytes, j);
            if (digit > 9)
            {
                //throw new Exception("Bad digit");
                this.ParsedSuccessfully = false;
                return this.ConvertAlphaNumEbcdic(ebcdicBytes);
            }
            intermediate = lo + digit;
            lo = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
            carry = intermediate >> 32;
            if (carry > 0)
            {
                intermediate = mid + carry;
                mid = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
                carry = intermediate >> 32;
                if (carry > 0)
                {
                    intermediate = hi + carry;
                    hi = intermediate & 0xffffffff;
                    carry = intermediate >> 32;
                    // carry should never be non-zero. Back up with validation
                }
            }
        }

        decimal result = new Decimal((int)lo, (int)mid, (int)hi, isNegative, (byte)decimalPlaces);
        return result.ToString();
    }

    private int Nibble(byte[] ebcdicBytes, int nibbleNo)
    {
        int b = ebcdicBytes[ebcdicBytes.Length - 1 - nibbleNo / 2];
        return (nibbleNo % 2 == 0) ? (b & 0x0000000F) : (b >> 4);
    }

    private bool ByteArrayIsFullOf_0xFF(byte[] ebcdicBytes)
    {
        if (ebcdicBytes == null || ebcdicBytes.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (byte b in ebcdicBytes)
        {
            if (b != 0xFF)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

LineTemplate class,FieldTemplate class,ParserUtilities class are present in page
Click [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673240/EBCDIC-to-ASCII-Converter)!

Issue happening in line 34 [image]

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but this _might_ help you: https://github.com/Maoni0/mem-doc/blob/master/doc/.NETMemoryPerformanceAnalysis.md

Comment: Are you running under debug mode or release?

Comment: `StreamWriter[]` here why declare multiple StreamWriters? single one + loop is enough. and better use `using (SteamWriter ...`

Comment: @David running in debug mode

Comment: sure @@Lei Yang , will change my code accordingly

Comment: When programming, check out every object creation in your code, and make sure you are releasing them properly after use if they are IDisposable. Otherwise you will always have possible problems. Never use GC to solve these problems. That will just cause more major problems.

Comment: Can't find where the StreamWriter gets initialized. And tell us which line throws the exception. Is that always the same line?

Comment: Consider using Spans and / or FileStream to reduce the amount of duplicate byte[] data in your parser implementation.

Comment: Check the size of your lines list within the parser. Also when using List<>.ToArray() the internal array of the list has to be copied, which can cause memory issues for large lists too.

Comment: @BentTranberg are you saying like set all the initialized variable to null ?

Comment: @shingo I have edited my code , please check and error occurs in same place Parsed line.CS (this is called by EbcdicParser class)

Comment: @PraveenN - Please remove all of the GC code and simply dispose of your streams. Can you let me know if the problem goes away?

Comment: @PraveenN - Also, you haven't shown the code in `ParserUtilities.ConvertLineArrayToCsv` so you might need to check if you're not disposing any streams there too.

Comment: @PraveenN - I've tried to run your code, but I don't have the `LineTemplate`, `FieldTemplate`, `ParserUtilities`, and `ParsedField` classes. Also the `FieldType` enum is missing. And, finally, the `EbcdicParser` doesn't have a `ParsedLines` property. Can you provide those?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have given the link for all the class now

Comment: @PraveenN - The article you have linked to contains a different version of the code. There is still no `ParsedLines` property and there is no `FieldType.String`, `FieldType.DateString`, `FieldType.BinaryNum`, `FieldType.DateStringMMDDYY` enums. Please don't waste our time. Please post your code that works. Sheesh!

Comment: "... saying like set all the initialized variable to null ?" No, that will not have the desired effect. Then the resource allocated will keep on living until the garbage collector comes around, which is too late. You will usually protect resources with a `using` statement. In rare cases you call Dispose explicitly, often then at the end of a `try-finally` statement. In some cases you also return a resource from a function, and then maybe it is the calling function that handles the disposal.

Comment: To sum up, you need to understand that pretty much every single precious resource (usually  some thingy that has the IDisposable interface) you allocate, also needs to be disposed immediately when no longer needed. It is urgent! If you open and read thousands of files in a loop, without also disposing those file resources at the end of each iteration, then you risk exhausting resources. Books, lessons, samples will usually skip this important point. You just have to get used to investigating whether every `new Thing()` you create needs explicit disposal.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the `System.OutOfMemoryException` is occurring because you have run out of file handles, not actual memory. You are creating a new `StreamWriter` for every file you process without disposing it.

See the documentation for a [System.OutOfMemoryException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=net-6.0). It specifically says:

> Although the garbage collector is able to free memory allocated to managed types, it does not manage memory allocated to unmanaged resources such as operating system handles (including handles to files, memory-mapped files, pipes, registry keys, and wait handles) and memory blocks allocated directly by Windows API calls or by calls to memory allocation functions such as malloc. Types that consume unmanaged resources implement the IDisposable interface.

> If you are consuming a type that uses unmanaged resources, you should be sure to call its IDisposable.Dispose method when you have finished using it. (Some types also implement a Close method that is identical in function to a Dispose method.) For more information, see the Using Objects That Implement IDisposable topic.

It's important to note that the Garbage Collector ***does not call `Dispose()`*** for you.

You must call `writer[i].Dispose()` when you have finished writing each stream.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of error

Comment: @PraveenN - Please let me know if that means you've tested calling `.Dispose()` on your stream and yet the error still occurs?

Comment: yes  I have also tried with .Dispose() method. I have also updated the entire code for reference

Answer (score 0):

Your garbage collection calls do not have the effect that you intend. Within your foreach loop, the `EbcdicParser parser` is still accessible because it is in scope of the currently executing function, so it is not considered for garbage collection.

Similarly, within your EbcdicParser, the byte array is still accessible, so it isn't cleared by your garbage collection call either.

Comment: However, in each subsequent iteration of the loop the previous parser is a candidate for collection. So, there is only one instance at a time that ***possibly** isn't collected. In reality, the compiler is often smart enough to see that the reference isn't used and may mark it as collectible even though it still has a reference at the end of each loop.

Comment: The compiler would mark it collectible? Isn't garbage collection a runtime process?

Also, because the contents of the array are being duplicated, there could be at least 2x the file size allocated but unused while the next iteration is running.

Comment: To be more precise, the compiler would release the reference at the earliest point possible in the loop, so then the run-time GC would see there are no references to the object and can clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Glenn, try put your parsing works in a method, and Enigmativity's advice, using a single StreamWriter.

```
static void Parse(.....)
{
    EbcdicParser parser = new EbcdicParser(File.FullName, lineTemplate);
    string Outputpath = "C:\\output\\" + File.Name + ".txt";
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(Outputpath))
    {
        foreach (ParsedLine line in parser.ParsedLines)
        {
             .....
        }
    }
}
```

Run GC outside the scope.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (FileInfo File in Files)
{
    Parse(......);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what you are getting from others, this is less of an answer, more of a bunch of suggestions (you have a lot of code in your question):

1. Like everyone else, I **strongly** recommend that you `Dispose` of everything that's *Disposable* (like the `StreamWriters`).
2. Remove the forced Garbage Collection calls (the calls to `GC.Collect`).  Somewhat ironically, those calls put more pressure on the GC (if you prematurely call `Collect`, you will end up promoting objects to Gen1 and Gen2 where collection costs more).
3. Rather than read the entire input file at once (which will do an allocation in the *Large Object Heap*), read your input in line by line or page by page.  Keep the individual allocations well below 85 kbytes.
4. If #3 isn't practical, find a way to reuse the same buffer on the reads (letting the buffer grow to its maximum needed size).
5. The way to measure memory issues is to run Performance Monitor (aka `Perfmon`) and use the *.NET Memory* counters.